# Problem in connecting to the SQLDeveloper ( no ocijdbc18 in java.library.path)

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to connect with my database using TNS Connection method but unable to do so because of this error -
**no ocijdbc18 in java.library.path**

[This is the exact error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jilDF.png)

Comment: Thanks! Now i'm able to connect with my db using another method by loading tns file

Comment: use TNS Network Alias and NOT Connect Identifier

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Additional (Third Party) JDBC drivers can be added to SQLDeveloper in the Preferences dialog. Select the Menu:

<kbd>Tools</kbd> - <kbd>Preferences</kbd>

Search for "JDBC" or select `Database`-`Third Party JDBC Drivers`. The drivers can be easily maintained on that screen:

[image]

Comment: this is for adding jdbc drivers - sqldev already ships a JDBC driver for Oracle DB, you could use this to add a driver for postgres for sql server...but no need for oracle. the error is complaining that sqldev can't find the OCI THICK resources for the connection vs JDBC THIN